# Delphi Unicode String Length in Bytes

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe4

I'm working on porting some Delphi 7 code to XE4, so, unicode is the subject here.

I have a method where a string gets written to a TMemoryStream, so according to [this embarcadero article](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38693),  I should multiply the length of the string (in characters) times the size of the Char type to get the length in bytes that is needed for the length (in bytes) parameter to WriteBuffer.

so before:

```
rawHtml : string; //AnsiString
...
memorystream1.WriteBuffer(Pointer(rawHtml)^, Length(rawHtml);
```

after:

```
rawHtml : string; //UnicodeString
...
memorystream1.WriteBuffer(Pointer(rawHtml)^, Length(rawHtml)* SizeOf(Char));
```

My understanding of Delphi's UnicodeString type is that it's UTF-16 internally. But my general understanding of Unicode is that not all unicode characters can be represented even in 2 bytes, that some corner case foreign characters will take 4 bytes. [Another of embarcadero's articles](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38437) seems to confirm that my suspicions, "In fact, it isn’t even always true that one Char is equal to two bytes!"

So...that leaves me wondering whether `Length(rawHtml)* SizeOf(Char)` is really going to be robust enough to be consistently accurate, or whether there's a better way to determine the size of the string that will be more accurate?

Comment: why don't you use `TStringStream` instead of `TMemoryStream`?

Comment: Ultimately the MemoryStream is passed to a TWebBrowser component to display. Pretty much every example I've seen of that has used MemoryStream. Would StringStream be a better choice for that purpose?

Comment: @Jessica In the end, they're both based on a `TStream` which means the internal structure of both work the same - it's just how you interact with it that's different. So even a `TFileStream` or `TResourceStream` are applicable to use in your case, that is, if you were sending Files or Resources to your browser anyway.

Comment: It still hurts that Delphi didn't just use UTF8 internally.

Comment: TStringStream is TMemoryStream descendant, so it makes sense to replace

Comment: @Roddy Delphi followed its platform, which chose its path before UTF8 was even invented.

Comment: @Roddy: I'm not sure it hurts at all. With UTF-16 you know that almost all characters are two bytes (yeah, the vast majority of them take up twice as much space as they have to, but space is seldom an issue these days). With UTF-8 you don't know that, unless you are strictly confined to English letters and punctuation.

Comment: @Andreas What use is knowing that most code points are a single character element? You still have to code for generality. UTF8 has lots of advantages. Had UTF8 been invented before NT and Java then I bet there would be no UTF16.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand : http://www.utf8everywhere.org/ @ David : yes, MS could have supported CP_UTF8 ins the 'fooA' API calls (in fact, they still could). I understand how we got to where we are, but it feels like a bit of a missed opportunity.

Comment: @David: Yes, I guess you are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My understanding of Delphi's UnicodeString type is that it's UTF-16
>   internally.

You are correct about UTF-16 encoding of Delphi's `UnicodeString`. This means what one 16-bit character is wide enough to represent all [code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) from the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) as exactly one `Char` element of `string` array.

> But my general understanding of Unicode is that not all
>   unicode characters can be represented even in 2 bytes, that some
>   corner case foreign characters will take 4 bytes.

However, you've got a little misconception here. `Length` function does not perform any deep inspection of characters and simply returns number of 16-bit `WideChar` elements, without taking into account any surrogates within your string. This means what if you assign a single character from any of [Supplementary Planes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) to the `UnicodeString`, `Length` will return 2.

```
program Egyptian;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

var
  S: UnicodeString;

begin
  S := #$1304E;  // single char
  Writeln(Length(S));
  Readln;
end.
```

---

**Conclusion**: byte size of string data is always fixed and equals `Length(S) * SizeOf(Char)`, no matter if `S` contains any variable-length characters.

Answer (score 12):

Delphi's `UnicodeString` is encoded with UTF-16. UTF-16 is a variable length encoding, just like UTF-8. In other words, a single Unicode code point may require multiple character elements to encode it. As a point of interest, the only fixed length Unicode encoding is UTF-32. The UTF-16 encoding uses 16 bit character elements, hence the name.

In a Unicode Delphi, `Char` is an alias for `WideChar` which is a UTF-16 character element. And `string` is an alias for `UnicodeString`, which is an array of `WideChar` elements. The `Length()` function returns the number of elements in the array.

So, `SizeOf(Char)` is always 2 for `UnicodeString`. Some Unicode code points are encoded with multiple character elements, or `Char`s. But `Length()` returns the number of characters elements and **not** the number of code points. The character elements all have the same size. So

```
memorystream1.WriteBuffer(Pointer(rawHtml)^, Length(rawHtml)* SizeOf(Char));
```

is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Others have explained how UnicodeString is encoded and how to calculate its byte length.  I just want to mention that the RTL already has such a function - `SysUtils.ByteLength()`:

```
memorystream1.WriteBuffer(PChar(rawHtml)^, ByteLength(rawHtml));
```

Comment: This is a really badly designed function mind you. It will accept strings other than UnicodeString but return rather useless values. Think through what happens when you pass it a UTF8String. I QC'ed this to no avail.

Comment: I read your QC report. Your proposed "solution" is not any better, because passing a `UnicodeString` to a `RawByteString` still performs a data conversion, this time from UTF-16 to Ansi, which can be lossy. `RawByteString` does not preserve `UnicodeString` data, only `AnsiString(N`) data. The correct solution is to overload `ByteLength()` on **both** `UnicodeString` and `RawByteString`, like other RTL functions do.

Comment: You are quite right. I will fix my QC report. It's probably a waste of time though because the report has never even been opened.

Comment: After you fix it, I can push it up to the next level.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is correct (with the sizeof(Char)).

What you refer to is that not one character refers to one code point (due to surrogate pairs for example). But the USC2 encoded (NOT UTF-16) characters in the string take up exactly the amount of bytes with `Length( Str ) * sizeof( Char )`.

Note that the Unicode encoding used in Delphi is the same as all Windows API call expect in the ....W variants.

Comment: What are you talking about? The question is about UTF16 and not about UCS2.

Comment: In UnicodeString UTF-16 is used, not the older UCS-2. So a code point can be made up of either one or two Chars. But as David explained, a surrogate pair is two Chars, and Length counts the number of Char elements, not the number of code points.

Comment: Windows strings have been UTF-16 since Windows 2000